# Is there any performance benefit from using a mismatched set of gpus to run dual monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

Here is the setup currently:

- Core i7 PC
- x1 GTX 660ti
- Monitor 1: LG 1080p connected via DVI
- Monitor 2: Samsung 1080p connected via DVI
- TV 1: Vizio 1080p connected via HDMI

I am going to add:

- x1 GTX 970
- Monitor: Asus ROG swift connected via display port

I'm wondering if there is any performance benefit to setting up my PC as follows:

- x1 GTX 970 to drive the Asus ROG Swift via display port
- x1 GTX 660ti driving the LG as a second display and the Viso TV as a mirror of the LG

The obvious other option is simply to drive all the displays via the GTX 970. I figured I would ask the question since having a 660ti sitting around seems like a bit of a waste. If it makes a difference in any of that I'm going to enable Gsync for the Asus display.

Comment: The 970 stock specification can power up to 4 displays on its on.  You would actually lose performance if you attempted to do what you describe

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think it provides any benefits over being able to hook up additional monitors. The system will still be using the primary GPU (the 970) for the framebuffer and 3D rendering for all attached displays unless you are running an SLI setup. If you have something that is particularly taxing with PhysX, it's possible to offload that to the 660ti, but that rarely makes a noticable improvement in games.

Comment: Compared to the 970 the 660 is trash

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did catch the video that Linus did [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbww3dhzK0M) on the topic of offloading PhysX. I wasn't really going for that though. I figured, the less workload for the GTX 907 the better. But hey, there are plenty of times the "Well it should" thought process doesn't pan out. Glad I asked the question.

Comment: As a professional OpenGL software engineer, I can tell you that under some very rare circumstances you might get a benefit. You would have to be running two different 3D rendering applications and have them output directly to the display (e.g. not in windowed mode). A lot of graphics software is not designed to let you select which render device you want to use, however... they basically assume that you want the same GPU that is driving the desktop. In the end, it does not make a lot of sense to use multiple GPUs to drive multiple monitors.

Comment: Thanks much Andon. I hope anyone who has the same idea I had finds your response.